# Reshaping an array into a nested array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array with multiple arrays nested inside of different length, how do I reshape a separate array that has an equal amount of values?

For example:

```
import numpy
array1 = numpy.array([[0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.4,0.5]],dtype=object)
array2 = numpy.array([0.11,0.22,0.33,0.44,0.55])
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
finalarray = numpy.array([[0.11,0.22,], [0.33,0.44,0.55]])
```

Comment: Treat `array1` as a list of arrays or lists, and iterate as needed.

Comment: @hpaulj has the right answer for the question here. `numpy` is not super useful with jagged arrays, so depending on how you're getting to this point, you might want to consider just sticking with Python lists.